# Keep updating Android UI from service, when activity is closed / restarted

Tags: android, user-interface, service, handler

Trying to figure this out for a while. I have got an app that runs a countdown in a separate `service` which calls `startsForeground`, displaying a notification. I start the countdown service from a button:

```
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),  PomoService.class);
            i.putExtra("EXTRA_MESSENGER", new Messenger(handler));
            startService(i);
```

and I update the UI with an `handler`, which received the bundle data telling how many milliseconds are left in the countdown, sent via message in the `onTick()` method:

```
Messenger messenger = (Messenger)extras.get("EXTRA_MESSENGER");
        Message msg = new Message();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putLong("remainingTime", millisUntilFinished);
        msg.setData(b);
        try {
            messenger.send(msg);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            Log.i("error", "error");
        }
```

And in the activity:

```
    private Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        long sentTime = msg.getData().getLong("remainingTime");
        textCountdownMin.setText(String.format("%02d", (sentTime/1000)/60));
        textCountdownSec.setText(":" + String.format("%02d", (sentTime/1000)%60));
    }
};
```

The whole setup works fine, the only problem is that if the user hits the back button or swipes away the app from the recent app list and then reopens it either from the drawer or the ongoing notification, the text is not being updated any more. The countdown is still ongoing though, as I can see it both from the notification being still displayed and from the fact that I use an AlarmManager to wake the screen, and that's fired up correctly.

Any clue on what measures I should take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved using a LocalBroadcastManager as outlined in this question: [Android update activity UI from service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14695537/android-update-activity-ui-from-service)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be using a dynamic Broadcast receiver. Create dynamic BR in your activity where u want to update the UI along with setting a intent filter along with a unique action. Then when ur service runs, inside the service create a new intent, set it a action that was set to intent filter and then send broadcast.