# An application stops by itself (or by Android OS)

Tags: android

I have an Android application which supposed to be active in the background all the time. I've built it as normal Android application. It works pretty fine, however, sometimes it stops by itself (or by Android OS) and have to re-run it. It's not because of an error caused, this is because it's a normal application, perhaps.

How do I make work all the time in the background?

**UPDATE**:

the application has GUI.

Comment: You should use Service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android OS may terminate a process at any given time due to memory constraints, you can learn [how Android manages memory here](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Understanding_Android_Application_and_Activity_Lifecycles). As @Karakuri mentioned starting a service would make it much less likely to be terminated, another plus for using service is that even in the event that it is killed the OS would try to resurrect at a later time when memory constraints permits:

> Note this means that most of the time your service is running, it may
>   be killed by the system if it is under heavy memory pressure. If this
>   happens, the system will later try to restart the service.

You can learn more detail on Services from the [Android dev site](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html).

Comment: can a service have GUI?

Comment: No, if it has GUI, it's not a service anymore. You can have an Activity and a Service together where Activity provides the GUI and service provides the background functionality. You can check this [StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14695537/android-update-activity-ui-from-service) for an idea on how to push changes from Service to Activity.

Answer (score 1):

Create a Service and call `startForeground()` to make it a foreground service. It doesn't prevent it from being killed, just makes it less likely as Android will try to keep it alive longer than non-foreground services. Note that you need to place an ongoing notification with an icon on the status bar when using a foreground service.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using a `Service`. If you return `START_STICKY` from `onStartCommand()` of service, then even if android has to terminate that service, it will be re-started as soon as the resources are free.

Comment: can a service have GUI?

Comment: @MariusKavansky A service can't directly display views like an activity, but a service can display active notifications (in the status bar), doing this makes it a foreground service.

Comment: I need this application to have GUI.