# Update textview of MainActivity from class that extends Service

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, textview

I'm trying to create an android app that communicate with Bluetooth low energy module. I am able to connect to module, read data and so on. But the problem is i do not know how to update textview from class that extends Service (the one in which whole connection to BLE is going on). I know there is like BILLION or even more posts like these, but believe me i tried.

Here is MainActivity: http://pastebin.com/6yaP0dYM

and here is a class that extends Service: http://pastebin.com/cYuAUina

If someone could provide me some tips to solve my issue that would be more than great!

Comment: in which method of ur service class you want to update textview

Comment: That is what i do not know exactly. Where should i :)? I tried to do this in onCharacteristicRead since in this one i take value from sensor..

Comment: ok please read about handler...you can update textview from service class using handler....i.e too easy n good..

Comment: Sure will do! thanks. Other suggestions are ofc welcome! :)

Comment: for more info n help connect me on fb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create Broadcast Receiver and broadcast that in Service.
If your Activity is ope, register receiver and in onReceive() update the UI.

The receiver should be in the Activity...

Below is the working code

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14695943/1403112

Comment: Thanks for reply :D ill let you know if this fix my issue :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get values through broadcast receiver......as follows, First create your own IntentFilter as,

```
Intent intentFilter=new IntentFilter();
intentFilter.addAction("YOUR_INTENT_FILTER");
```

Then create inner class BroadcastReceiver as,

```
  private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    /** Receives the broadcast that has been fired */
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(intent.getAction()=="YOUR_INTENT_FILTER"){
           //HERE YOU WILL GET VALUES FROM BROADCAST THROUGH INTENT EDIT YOUR TEXTVIEW///////////
           String receivedValue=intent.getStringExtra("KEY");
        }
    }
};
```

Now Register your Broadcast receiver in `onResume()` as,

```
registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
```

And finally Unregister BroadcastReceiver in `onDestroy()` as,

```
unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
```

Now the most important part...You need to fire the broadcast from wherever you need to send values..... so do as,

```
Intent i=new Intent();
i.setAction("YOUR_INTENT_FILTER");
i.putExtra("KEY", "YOUR_VALUE");
sendBroadcast(i);
```

....cheers :)

Comment: Thanks for reply :D ill let you know if this fix my issue :)