# Control an application from a service

Tags: android, service

I've written an application which has multiple activities with multiple buttons. A colleague of mine wrote a service which detects gestures, based on the gyroscope sensor (move up, down, rotation...). We want to join the application and the service so we would be able to control the app using gestures from the service.

Since we both don't have so much experience with Android, we'd like to ask, how this is usually achieved?

Comment: what was your effort?code?researches? 

Welcome to Stack Overflow! 
please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Service -> Activity communication you can use [LocalBroadcastManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html), check this SO answer: [Android update activity UI from service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14695537/android-update-activity-ui-from-service)

For the Activity -> Service communication you either start service and add extras to intent or have a bound service.
Make sure you read this article: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html