# Service Android How to refresh ui Activity if app is open?

Tags: java, android, user-interface, service

I want to create a service that runs in the background,
service upload files to a server .
meanwhile you can close the app .
the service continues to work ,
at the end and, if the app is open must update the UI of the app .
as you update the UI of the app if it's open ?
I have to make a check of the type : if app open ui update ?and how to do this ?

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14695537/android-update-activity-ui-from-service

Comment: use a "local bound service" pattern, what you need from your `Activity` is simply call `bindService`

Answer (score 0):

Use an event bus, such as [greenrobot's EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) or [`LocalBroadcastManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html). The service can post a message to the bus, announcing any state changes. The activity — if it exists — can subscribe for messages from the bus and update the UI upon receipt of this state-change message.

I have sample apps demonstrating this [for greenrobot's EventBus](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/EventBus/GreenRobot) and [for `LocalBroadcastManager`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/EventBus/LocalBroadcastManager). I also have one [for Square's Otto](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/EventBus/Otto), though it is a bit more complicated due to threading issues.