# Constantly updating textview

Tags: android

I have a service class which updates a static variable in my activity, I am having trouble trying to create code that will constantly run every 5 seconds to update say a textview.. using this variable.

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: Look into using LocalBroadcastReceiver or an event bus.

Comment: Use LocalBroadcastReceiver

Comment: create TextView Object as static and change it from your service

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android update activity UI from service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14695537/android-update-activity-ui-from-service)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a handler for running every 5 seconds
See this sample code

```
    Handler h = new Handler();
int delay = 5000; //milliseconds

h.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        //do something
        h.postDelayed(this, delay);
    }
}, delay);
```

and in run method you can update your textview

Comment: Thank you, it's telling me delay is accessed within inner class, needs to be declared final?

Comment: declare your textview  final then

Comment: Worked a charm, had to declare delay and the handler final. thanks so much.

Comment: don't forget to accept the answer and also upvote it