# Calling a new layout from a class

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I was wondering if it's possible to use setContentView on a class? I'm planning to call a new layout once the class is called. So basically, I'm trying to change the view once I detect an nfc tag.

Main_Activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main__screen);
    readCard = new ReadCard(this);
    enableReaderMode();
}

public void enableReaderMode()
{
    Activity activity = this;
    NfcAdapter nfc = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(activity);
    if (nfc != null)
    {
        nfc.enableReaderMode(activity, readCard, READER_FLAGS, null);
    }

}
```

Class

```
private Main_Screen mainScreen;
private Context context;
public String PINHolder = null;

IsoDep isoDep;
Activity Main_Screen = (Activity) context;
public ReadCard(Main_Screen mainScreen)
{
    this.mainScreen = mainScreen;
}
@Override
public void onTagDiscovered(Tag tag)
{


    isoDep = IsoDep.get(tag);

    if (isoDep != null)
    {
        beepSound.start();
        try
        {
            isoDep.connect();
            mainScreen.setContentView(R.layout.pin_login);
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: An activity is a type of class... you can call it in an activity. Or just recall it once the class is called with an intent for the activity to update it's view

Comment: You want to change the View after you instantiated an object? Is that it?

Comment: @SQLiteNoob - I'm try to call a method from a class to change the layout view.
Mauker - somehow yes. I'm trying to call it from a different class' method.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I follow. Why can't you just call `setContentView` again?

Comment: if you're just calling another class without changing the activity, Mauker is right

Comment: That's what I am trying to do now. Unfortunately it is not changing. I get the error "only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views"

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: I'll update the post to place the code.

Comment: I guess the right term would be opening a new layout using a class instead of a button perhaps?

Comment: It all depends on what exactly are you trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do what you want that way, because only the `Activity` is "authorized" to modify its contents and children Views. You also can't touch the UI Thread from a background one.

There are some ways you can achieve what you want, I'll try to list some:

- You could "send a message" to the `Activity` once your class did what it was supposed to do. You can do that by using the [`LocalBroadcastManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) (as seem on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14695537/android-update-activity-ui-from-service)), or [Greenrobot's EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus);
- You could try to use some sort of listener;
- Use [Handlers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html).

For more info on how you can communicate with the UI thread (in this case, with your `Activity`), check the [Android training guide](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html).

Comment: Alright. Thank you very much. At least I got a clarification that what I am doing will not work. Thank you very much!