# Passing ArrayList of values between two activities.. Error

Tags: android, android-intent

I tried to pass ArrayList of values between two Activities  but I am getting error as below.Thanks in Advance

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Bundle android.content.Intent.getExtras()' on a null object reference at com.example.android.myapplication.DetailActivity.getextras1(DetailActivity.java:35) at com.example.android.myapplication.MyService.onStartCommand(MyService.java:38) at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3180) at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:182)  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1595)  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5763)  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)

code which is used to Call Other activity

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
 @Override
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){

  String[] appdescription =  getResources().getStringArray(R.array.appdescriptionname);
  final String appdescipl = appdescription[position];
  final int imagesList =  noImagesList[position];
  final int imagesList2 = noImagesList2[position];

  Intent intent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DetailActivity.class);
  intent1.putExtra("des","mydes");
  intent1.putExtra("appdescipl" , appdescipl);
  intent1.putExtra("imagesList",imagesList);
  intent1.putExtra("imagesList2",imagesList2);
  startActivity(intent1);
     }
});
```

DetailActivity

```
public class DetailActivity extends Activity {



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.detail_activity);
    this.getextras1();
    this.getdescriptionofapp1();
    this.getImage1ofapp1();
    this.getImage2ofapp1();
    startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));


}


public Bundle getextras1() {
    Bundle extras1 = getIntent().getExtras();
    return extras1;
}

public TextView getdescriptionofapp1() {
    TextView descriptionofapp1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.descriptionofapp);
    return descriptionofapp1;
}

public ImageView getImage1ofapp1() {
    ImageView image1ofapp1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);
    return image1ofapp1;
}

public ImageView getImage2ofapp1() {
    ImageView image2ofapp1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image2);
    return image2ofapp1;
}




}
```

MyService

```
public class MyService extends Service {


public String description;
public int image1;
public int image2;


@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    DetailActivity i ;
    i = new DetailActivity();
    Bundle extras = i.getextras1();
    TextView descriptionofapp = i.getdescriptionofapp1();
    ImageView image1ofapp  = i.getImage1ofapp1();
    ImageView image2ofapp = i.getImage2ofapp1();



    if ( extras.containsKey("des")){

        description = extras.getString("appdescipl");
        descriptionofapp.setText(description);
        image1 = extras.getInt("imagesList");
        image1ofapp.setImageResource(image1);
        image2 = extras.getInt("imagesList2");
        image2ofapp.setImageResource(image2);
    }

    else if (extras.containsKey("data")){
        description = extras.getString("appdatadescipl");
        descriptionofapp.setText(description);
        image1 = extras.getInt("imagesOfLists");
        image1ofapp.setImageResource(image1);
        image2 = extras.getInt("imagesOfLists2");
        image2ofapp.setImageResource(image2);
    }

    this.onDestroy();
    return START_STICKY;
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {

    this.stopSelf();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proble is here

```
DetailActivity i ;
i = new DetailActivity();
Bundle extras = i.getextras1();
```

You are creating new `instance` of `Activity` class but you assinged your `bundle` in another `instance` of the `Activity`.

You can pass `bundle` to your service with `putExtra` method of `intent` and `getExtra` in the service to extract it.

**use receiver to update your view from service. Your approch is wrong.**

Have a look at there 
[Android update activity UI from service](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14695943/7267105)

Answer (score 0):

use specific putextra for each object :

```
intent1.putStringExtra("des","mydes");
intent1.putStringExtra("appdescipl" , appdescipl);
intent1.putIntExtra("imagesList",imagesList);
intent1.putIntExtra("imagesList2",imagesList2);
```

and then use equal getExtra in DetailActivity

```
getIntent().getStringExtra("des");
getIntent().getStringExtra("appdescipl");
getIntent().getIntExtra("imagesList");
getIntent().getIntExtra("imagesList2");
```

i hope it would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Better to use Parcelable Object for multiple parameters.
Suppose you have a class Foo implements Parcelable properly , To put it into Intent in an Activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DetailActivity.class);
Foo foo = new Foo();
intent.putExtra("foo ", foo);
startActivity(intent);
```

To get it from intent in DetailActivity:-

```
Foo foo = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("foo");
String appDisc = foo.getDisc();
int appImage1 = foo.getImage1();
int appImage2 = foo.getImage2();
....
```

I hope it would be helpful.