# How to display data and update its value in android

Tags: android

I am developing a simple `android` application that receive a `json` string from a background service via `websocket`. The `json` data is changed overtime. For example, the `json` string is:

```
{"app":"events","command":"handleEvents","args":{"eventId":16,"name":"X2_PA_STATE","params":[0]}}
```

Since the params value is changing all the time, how do I display it via `TextView` and auto update its value? I have tried event listener but it seems not to work.

Comment: What event listener have you tried? If you're listening to a change via the background service, you should handle your updating within it.

Comment: If you are trying to update data through background service, it would be better to Bind your service into your activity/fragment use ServiceConnection to communicate or you can BroadcasteReceiver .

Comment: I created a custom listener, but I cant seems to post the code here

Comment: the background service is not a part of my application, it is an external apps that send data via websocket where my application listen to and extract that data to display

Answer (score 0):

Android has a built-in JSON Parser.

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(<res_json_string>);
String app = obj.optString("app");
String command = obj.optString("command");
JSONObject args = obj.optJSONObject("args");
String eventId = args.optString("eventId");
String name = args.optString("name");
JSONArray p = args.optJSONArray("params");
ArrayList<String> params = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0; i < p.length; i++){
   params.add(p.get(i));
}
```

Since you are in background Service you have to use `Handler` or `BroadcastReceiver` to achieve this task. (Only from UI thread you can update UI)

see this link for example [Updating UI from Service](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14695943/5235032)

Hope this helps, Happy coding!!

Comment: Sorry that I am not being clear about the so called "background service". it is not part of the android Eco system. it is an external application running along with. I am able to parse the JSON, but dont know how to display it and update when the value changed

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have some kind of websocket service, not related with Android at all, that sends data. The part you may be missing is adding a websocket implementation to your Android app, to listen your websocket service and parse the data. Then, you could just call `textview.setText()` method to update the textview value every time you receive data from the websocket.

In that case, take a look to OkHttp WebSocket implementation

https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/WebSocket.html