# Updating Activity when it comes back to the Foreground after data has already been retrieved

Tags: java, android, rx-java2

- I have implemented a `Service` that receives notifications sent from
  the server.
- I'm currently using a broadcast receiver to send data. The Broadcast Listener is updating the `Activity` just fine. However, when data is sent when the Activity is not on "onResume" state, the data is not received.
- I got interested in using RXjava because I believe it could resolve the issue but don't know where to start.

**The problem:** 
When the activity is not on **the foreground**, the Activity is not updating.

Not in the foreground: Meaning that I have called `unregisterReceiver` to unregister in my `onPause` method.

**My current user case:** I'm using a `Service` to intercept notification sent from server using FCM

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "[" + MyFirebaseMessagingService.class.getName() + "]=";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNewToken(String token) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + token);
        }

    /**
     * Handle time allotted to BroadcastReceivers.
     */
    private void handleNow() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Short lived task is done.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {


        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());

            // Handle message within 10 seconds
            handleNow();
        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }

        // <-----------RX JAVA Observable Implementation----------->
        // I would like to use Rx java to send data to my activity ONLY if the activity is in the foreground
        // because data will be used to update the UI
    }

    @Override
    public void onDeletedMessages() {
        super.onDeletedMessages();
    }
}
```

I looked into `RXjava` and I find out that the library takes care of asynchronous operations, but what I'm curious about is:
if there is any functions within `RXjava` that will automatically update that data once the Activity is back on the foreground?

If not, what are the other alternatives?

*Maybe this question has already been answered but I could not find a precise user case to what I'm trying to achieve in here. Also, I might be asking the question wrongly, but that just explains my confusion here*

Comment: To update data once the activity back on the foreground you can register as a lifecycle observer. Look at LiveData source code you will get the solution.

Comment: notificatin data is very small so you can save in shared prefs and later when the activity resumes display it form prefs

Comment: I went ahead and used RxJava that does the job using the function onNext on the observable and observer.

Comment: I agree with Har Kal. You can store this in a SharedPref and reference that once the Activity starts again. Very simple. This is what I am doing.