# NetworkOnMainThreadException OR OnErrorNotImplementedException RxAndroid send/receive data to/from bound service

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-android, synchronous, okhttp

I am using the updated version of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14695943/3016293) to link (bind) an activity to a service.

**MyService.java**

```
public class MyService extends Service {

   private LocalBinder binder = new LocalBinder();
   private Observable<Integer> responseObservable;
   private ObservableEmitter<Integer> responseObserver;

   public static boolean isRunning = false;

   @Nullable
   @Override
   public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
      return binder;
   }

   @Override
   public int onStartCommand(@Nullable Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
       GsonConverterFactory factory = GsonConverterFactory.create(new GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create());

      HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
      interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

      Client client = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .client(new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                 .addInterceptor(interceptor)
                 .build())
            .addConverterFactory(factory)
            .build()
            .create(Client.class);

      for (//some loop) {
          Response<Result> response = client.search(//some params here)
                           .execute();
          responseObserver.onNext(response.code());
      }
      return START_NOT_STICKY;
   }

   @Override
   public void onDestroy() {
      super.onDestroy();
      isRunning = false;
   }

   public Observable<Message> observeResponse() {
      if (responseObservable == null) {
         responseObservable = Observable.create(em -> responseObserver = em);
         responseObservable = responseObservable.share();
      }
      return responseObservable;
   }


   public class LocalBinder extends Binder {

      public DService getService() {
         return MyService.this;
      }
   }

}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivityextends AppCompatActivity {

   private MyService service;
   private Disposable disposable;

   private ServiceConnection serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
      @Override
      public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder iBinder) {
         service = ((MyService.LocalBinder) iBinder).getService();
         disposable = service.observeResponse()
               .observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
               .subscribe(responseCode -> updateUI()); //this must run on main thread
         startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyService.class));
      }

      @Override
      public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
      }
   };

   @Override
   protected void onDestroy() {
      if (disposable != null)
         disposable.dispose();
      unbindService(serviceConnection);
      super.onDestroy();
   }

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       //....

       Button start = findViewById(R.id.start);
       start.setOnClickListener(v -> {
           Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
           bindService(intent, serviceConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
       });

       //....
   }
}
```

If I use `observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())`, I get `NetworkOnMainThreadException`, and if I use `observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())`, I get `OnErrorNotImplementedException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.`

I know what both errors mean, in normal cases I can resolve them easily, but here nothing I normally do work.

I need the network requests in the service to be executed synchronously because it is in a loop, and I treat each request result in order, asynchronous calls are not an option for me.

I tried `runOnUiThread(() -> updateUI())`, but it produces the same error. I also tried to execute the service on a new thread, but still the same error too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of `Service` runs on Main Thread

> A service runs in the main thread of its hosting process; the service
>   does not create its own thread and does not run in a separate process
>   unless you specify otherwise. If your service is going to perform any
>   CPU-intensive work or blocking operations, such as MP3 playback or
>   networking, you should create a new thread within the service to
>   complete that work. By using a separate thread, you can reduce the
>   risk of Application Not Responding (ANR) errors, and the application's
>   main thread can remain dedicated to user interaction with your
>   activities. [REFERENCE](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services)

So, making api calls in Service directly will cause `NetworkOnMainThreadException` in all cases.

1. When you put `observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())`, you are definitly bound to have `NetworkOnMainThreadException`; reason specified above
2. When you put `observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())`, the api call in service causes `NetworkOnMainThreadException`; but since you have used `Rx` it returns an error message to its subscriber; but in your case, you have not added error part.

You have used:

`subscribe(responseCode -> updateUI());`

to prevent app crash, you have to use

`subscribe(responseCode -> updateUI(), error -> error.printStackTrace());`

**Now to fix the issue:**

1. In service, make sure to call API on new Thread in Service;

OR

2. You can also try to make API call using reference to another class(like Presenter in MVP), where you make API calls and send response to UI directly using :

   ```
      service.observeResponse()
          .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
          .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
          .subscribe(responseCode -> view.updateUI(), error -> view.displayError())
   ```

Comment: I remember trying to call api from a new thread, and it was not working. Now it is working, maybe I was doing something wrong. thank you anyway :)