# Changing non-static values from a static method

Tags: java, android, static, non-static

So I am making an application which has a handler in the main class/activity.
I got the warning I should declare it static to prevent memory leaks.
So, I read some articles which explain the issue and I know understand it (and changed the handler to static and to use a weakreference).

But, here comes my problem:
I need the handler to change certain non-static vars (or call a method which does that). I do not want to declare these vars static as it wouldn't make much sense (they should belong to an instance of the main class, not to the class itself).

How should I do this?

I have already seen a block of code where someone created an instance of the main class and then used that to change the values of non-static vars or to call non-static methods.
That seems very strange to me because when creating that new instance and using vars from that instance, how can my program ever know I'm talking about the same "myInt" or "myString" as I was earlier in the program.

Forgive me if this makes no sense or if I didn't explain it well, I'm still newb

Comment: You need an `Interface`.  Your handler implements an update method which notifies consumers when something interesting happens.  The consumers (class instances) implement the same interface and receive a callback when that something happens.  Like an `onClickListener` but defined your way. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14660671/how-to-notify-an-activity-when-globalvariables-are-changed/14660808#14660808

Answer (score 0):

You can keep a reference to the main class in a static variable (assuming there's only one instance of the main class), or else you can pass a reference to the main class as a parameter to the static method

You are correct that you don't want to instantiate a new main class in the static method - this won't affect any other copies of the main class (unless you're only changing the copy's static methods/properties, in which case you ought to be able to do this without an instance of the main class)

Comment: This looks to me like nothing but slightly more complex static variables.

Comment: @Keppil I agree but what could I do to solve my problem? Should I create a static variable with the value "this"? I think there must be a better/more correct way to do what I want

Comment: @arijspieter: I think you have some kind of design problem. There is, as far as I know, no sensible way for a static method to update non-static methods, it simply shouldn't have to.

Comment: It's just that stupid handler which wants to be static, but I think I'll just make the handler non-static again. Memory leaks won't occur anyway since Messages don't get delayed. thanks for your answers